# What is the intuition behind loss functions in regression? Can I create one? What rules should I follow?

Tags: regression, estimation, inference, regression-coefficients, loss-functions

My question arises after reading this [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/08/comprehensive-guide-regression/), which presents 7 methods of regression, we know that each of these methods is determined by a loss function, my question is **What is the intuition behind these loss functions?**

I arrived at that link since in my study I am trying to find a loss function that is concave with respect to the random variables, that is, we know that a regression problem consists of estimating the parameter $\beta_{*}\in  \mathbb{R}^{d}$ which allows expressing
$$ Y_{i} = β_{*}^{T}X_{i} + e_{i} $$
where $ Y_{i} \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ X_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, $ i= 1, \ldots, n $. In order to estimate the parameter $ \beta_{*}$ what is attempted is  to minimize a loss function $ l(x, y, \beta) $, for example, the quadratic loss function is common  when using least squares techniques. The quadratic loss is given by $ l (x, y, \beta) = (y- \beta^{T} x)^{2}$, the reason why it is intuitive to use the quadratic loss function is obvious from the point of view of linear algebra, but note that this is convex with respect to $ w = (x, y) $.

**My intention is to construct or find a loss function $ l (x, y, β) $ that is concave with respect to $ w = (x, y) $ and that I can justify within the context of regression methods.**

Comment: You could maximize the likelihood of the corresponding probability model. It's well-established that these functions are concave in some specific circumstances for linear models.

Comment: That's not a very good article at all.  For example this: "The independent variables should not be correlated with each other..." is just false.

Comment: You want a function such that minimizing it leads to predictions with good properties. This sounds like the definition of a *proper scoring rule*, see [Gneiting](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~shaddin/cs699fa17/docs/GR07.pdf) or search this site.